# Store and Load objects from a file

Tags: c++, file, class

I'm making this program for class and we are supposed to store objects from a class in a file and then load them. But I always get the last object stored instead of the first. Tried the seekp function but it doesn't work. Also shouldn't the size of an object be 38 bytes, instead of the 48 i'm getting?

```
void student::load()
{
fstream fin;
fin.open("StudentData.bin",ios::binary|ios::in);
fin.read((char*)this,sizeof(*this));
}
void student::store(int z)
{
fstream fout;
fout.open("StudentData.bin",ios::binary|ios::out);
//fout.seekp(38*z, fout.beg)
cout<<sizeof(*this); 
fout.write((char*)this,sizeof(*this));
}


for(i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    s[i].store(i);
}
cout<<"Done!";
student pleb;
pleb.load();
pleb.showstudent();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: I guess that each your call to `fout.open` overwrites the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `fout.open()` rewrites the file each time. If you want to *append* to file, that is, to have each `store()` call to write that `student` after all other students already written, then you can use the `ios::app` flag.

Or, better, do not open the file in `store()` at all. Make your `store()` actuall accept the stream as a parameter; then open the file in the main program (once per all students) and pass the stream to `store()`. Not only this will solve your problem, but will also make your `student` class more configurable as it will be easy to write to any file, or in general to any stream the user of `student` needs.

BTW, also make sure that it is *correct* to write your `student`s this way. For example, if you have any pointers in your `student` (including, say, `std::string` members as they have pointers inside), you will not get what you expect.

As for the object size, it is impossibly to answer not seeing the whole declaration of `student` class.

Comment: 4 ints and 30 chars. Took your advise, can't seem to pass a stream as argument tho.

Comment: @Yolo, "4 ints and 30 chars" sound more like 46 bytes, as `int` is most probably 4 byte on modern systems. But you'd better ask this as a separate question and include the whole `student` class definition. For not passing a stream, that's strange. Just make sure to pass it _by reference_: `student::store(int z, fstream& fout)`